# Probability that all three dice land on four

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This problem comes from a homework assignment that was I turned in but got incorrect... I'm not sure where I went wrong...

Here's the problem

Suppose we have 8 fair die and 3 unfair die where the unfair die have 4 dots on all 6 sides. Randomly select 3 die to roll simultaneously. Find the probability that all 3 die land with 4 dots facing up.

My attempt:
We'll use the complement rule:

Let E be the event that all 3 die land on 4 dots
$$P(E) = 1 - P(\text{at least 1 non-4}) = 1 - P(E^{c})$$
Looking for the complement's probability:
$$P(E^{c}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{3} P(\text{i die land on non-4s})$$

Then
$$P(\text{i die land on non-4s}) = P(\text{i fair die chosen} \bigcap \text{at least one of the i die is non-4}) \\= P(\text{i fair die chosen}) P(\text{at least one of the i die is non-4}) \\P(\text{i fair die chosen})= \frac{{8 \choose i} {3 \choose 3 - i}}{11 \choose 3} $$
$$P(\text{at least one of the i die is non-4}) = \sum_{n = 1}^{n = i} (\frac{5}{6})^{n}(\frac{1}{6}) ^{3 - n}$$

So then,
$$P(\text{i die land on non-4s}) = \frac{{8 \choose i} {3 \choose 3 - i}}{11 \choose 3} \sum_{n = 1}^{n = i} (\frac{5}{6})^{n}(\frac{1}{6}) ^{3 - n}$$

$$P(E^{c}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{3} P(\text{i die land on non-4s}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{3} \frac{{8 \choose i} {3 \choose 3 - i}}{11 \choose 3} \sum_{n = 1}^{n = i} (\frac{5}{6})^{n}(\frac{1}{6}) ^{3 - n}$$

which leads us to
$$P(E) = 1 - P(\text{at least 1 non-4}) = 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^{3} \frac{{8 \choose i} {3 \choose 3 - i}}{11 \choose 3} \sum_{n = 1}^{n = i} (\frac{5}{6})^{n}(\frac{1}{6}) ^{3 - n}$$

Does my logic make sense? My professor just marked my attempt as wrong without feedback, so I'm confused about where I went wrong? Did I overcount somewhere? What's the approach I should be taking if not this one?

Comment: You're almost correct. In the summation, you should have $(\frac{5}{6})^n(\frac{1}{6})^{i-n}$ because you have $i$ fair die and you want some non-empty subset of them to land on a non-4. Currently you have $3-n$ but one or more of those $3$ die could be the non-fair ones.